# Checksums aren't martching for kubuntu

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, iso, hash

I have downloaded kubuntu 18.04.2 from [here](https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/). I verified ISO by sha256 checksums, surprisingly they are different. 
The sha256sum for ISO:

```
844762a208593ee5cf396cb09522b1dfa127c65b79f71f4863c062039215d0d8  kubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
```

but checksum in file SHA256SUMS was:

```
22580b9f3b186cc66818e60f44c46f795d708a1ad86b9225c458413b638459c4 *ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
```

While downloading the file there was no internet connection problem but since my service provider gives me only 1GB daily. When it was ended I switched to another connecttion but my download wasn't paused. It was finished in an hour. Why are the checksums different? Is my download incorrect? Do I need to download again?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear.

If you are getting `844762a208593ee5cf396cb09522b1dfa127c65b79f71f4863c062039215d0d8` for your file, then that is correct.

If you are getting `22580b9f3b186cc66818e60f44c46f795d708a1ad86b9225c458413b638459c4` for your file, then somehow, you have downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04.2 desktop iso version instead of the kubuntu version.

I downloaded the kubuntu iso:

```
doug@s15:~/iso$ shasum -a 256 kubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
844762a208593ee5cf396cb09522b1dfa127c65b79f71f4863c062039215d0d8  kubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
doug@s15:~/iso$ ls -l kubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 doug doug 1923727360 Jun 13 23:57 kubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
```

which is the correct checksum.

Comment: Well it is kubuntu version, I have tested it in live mode it works fine, I am doubtful whether to install it or not. Since hashes aren't matching. I downloaded the checksums from http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/

Comment: I don't know what to say, that checksum is for Ubuntu, not kubuntu.

Comment: Where can I get checksums for kubuntu?

Comment: You have the correct checksum for kubuntu.

Comment: So, why both the hashes are different.

Comment: Because you downloaded the incorrect iso, based on what you described as what you wanted.

Comment: Should I install kubuntu using this iso? Will it cause any problem.

Comment: If something is wrong with this iso please suggest me the correct one or provide a link for kubuntu iso for desktop.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your ISO but it won't install Kubuntu, it will install plain Ubuntu. You can of course install  KDE over it afterwards.